# Why debounce doesnt invoke my function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, mobx, debouncing

Im working on something with **React** and **mobx**.

I created an ***ImageCarousel Component*** where I show the image that was clicked.
I have a **previous** and a **next** buttons(which are themselves a Component), to move between images.

I tried to wrap those actions (**prev** and **next**) with `lodash debounce`,
but something fails on the way.

My current store has those actions:

- `prevCarousel`
- `nextCarousel`
- `debounceAction`

**`debounceAction`** is just a Higher Order Function that get 2 parameters (fn, wait), and invoke `lodash debounce` with those parameters.

My CarouselButton component get through its props those actions I mantioned above. inside the Component I trigger with `onClick` event to invoke `debounceAction(fn, wait)` with the actual action (**prev**, or **next**).

Im not sure how to wrap my actions with debounce the right way.

I invoke `debounceAction` (the *HOF* that wraps the debounce) in the second code snippet (in **CarouselButton Component**).

do you see my mistake here?

*galleryStore.jsx* - current Store:

```
class GalleryStore {

    // Observables    
    @observable images = [
        // ....images
    ];

    @observable carouselleButtons= {
        next: "fa fa-chevron-right",
        back: "fa fa-chevron-left"
    }
    @observable selectedImageIndex = null;
    @observable hideCarousel = true;
    @observable onTransition = false;

  // Actions
    selectImage = (index) =>{
        this.selectedImageIndex = index;
    }

    toggleCarousel = () =>{
        this.hideCarousel = !this.hideCarousel;
    }

    carouselNext = () => {
        if(this.selectedImageIndex == this.images.length - 1) {
            return;
        }

        this.onTransition = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.selectedImageIndex = this.selectedImageIndex + 1;
            this.onTransition = false;
        },500)
    }

    carouselPrev = () => {
        if(this.selectedImageIndex == 0) {
            console.log('start of the collection');          
            return;
        } 

        this.onTransition = true; 
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.selectedImageIndex = this.selectedImageIndex - 1;
            this.onTransition = false;        
        }, 500)       
    }

    debounceAction = (fn, wait) => {
        //lodash's debounce
        return debounce(fn, wait);
    }
```

*carouselButton Component* - **here I Invoke the debounce**:

```
// React's
import React from 'react';

// Styles
import CarouselButtonStyle from './carouselButtonStyle';

// CarouselButton Component
export default class CarouselButton extends React.Component {
    debounce = (e) =>{
        const { debounceAction } = this.props;

        // ----->    HERE I CALL DEBOUNCE !   <---------
        e.stopPropagation();
        debounceAction(this.buttonHandler, 400);
    }

    buttonHandler = (e) => {
        const {limit, index, action, debounceAction} = this.props;

        if(index == limit)  return;
        else action();
    }

    render(){
        const {limit, index, icon, action, debounceAction} = this.props;

        return(
            <CarouselButtonStyle 
                onClick={(e) => {this.debounce(e)}} 
                className={ index == limit ? 'end-of-collection' : '' } >

                <i className={icon} aria-hidden="true" />
            </CarouselButtonStyle>
        );
    }
}
```

*imageCarousel.jsx* - carouselButton **parent** Component:

```
// React's
import React from 'react';

// Mobx-react's
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

// Styles
import ImageCarouselStyle from './imageCarouselStyle';

// Components
import ImgContainer from './imgContainer/imgContainer';
import CarouselButton from './carouselButton/carouselButton';

// ImageCarousel Component
@inject('galleryStore')
@observer
export default class ImageCarousel extends React.Component {
    closeCarousel = () => {
        this.props.galleryStore.toggleCarousel();
    }

    onKeyDown = (e) => {
        const { keyCode } = e;

        if(keyCode ===27) this.onEscHandler();
        else if (keyCode == 37) this.onLeftArrow();
        else if (keyCode == 39) this.onRightArrow();
        else return;
    }

    onLeftArrow = () => { this.props.galleryStore.carouselPrev()  }

    onRightArrow = () => { this.props.galleryStore.carouselNext() }

    onEscHandler = () => { this.closeCarousel() }

    componentDidMount(){
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown, false);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ImageCarouselStyle 
                hidden={this.props.galleryStore.hideCarousel}
                onClick={this.closeCarousel} >

                <CarouselButton action={'prev'} 
                    icon={this.props.galleryStore.carouselleButtons.back} 
                    action={this.props.galleryStore.carouselPrev}
                    limit={0}
                    index={this.props.galleryStore.selectedImageIndex} 
                    debounceAction={this.props.galleryStore.debounceAction} />

                <ImgContainer 
                    images={this.props.galleryStore.images} 
                    imgIndex={this.props.galleryStore.selectedImageIndex} 
                    onTransition={this.props.galleryStore.onTransition}/>

                <CarouselButton action={'next'} 
                    icon={this.props.galleryStore.carouselleButtons.next} 
                    action={this.props.galleryStore.carouselNext} 
                    limit={this.props.galleryStore.amountOfImages}
                    index={this.props.galleryStore.selectedImageIndex} 
                    debounceAction={this.props.galleryStore.debounceAction} /> 

            </ImageCarouselStyle>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the failure you are experiencing? Are there console errors?

Comment: @RobertFarley I get no errors. I think the function i pass to the debounce just does not invoke. maybe i didn't write it correctly?

Comment: I do not know React and mobx, but: lodash's debounce creates (and returns) a function, hence debounceAction() returns this function, and at the line ("HERE I CALL DEBOUNCE !") the return value of debounceAction() is not used, so nobody actually calls that function. This would call it: `debounceAction(this.buttonHandler, 400)();` - but you are using debounce wrong: you may not call debounce() again and again as in your implementation; you have to call debounce() only once, and then call the _result_ of debounce() again and again.

Comment: `return debounce(action(fn), wait)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have to return `debounceAction` from `CarouselButton`'s `debounce` method.

```
debounce = (e) =>{
    const { debounceAction } = this.props;

    // ----->    HERE I CALL DEBOUNCE !   <---------
    e.stopPropagation();
    debounceAction(this.buttonHandler, 400);
// -^^^ must return here
}
```

However, I would suggest going a step further to avoid future confusion. Simply invoke lodash's `debounce` when you need it, rather than rewriting it multiple times in your code and leading to questionable method names.

Here is the most basic example of how you can wrap a click handler:

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  handleClick = _.debounce((e) => {
    alert('debounced click reaction')
  }, 1000)

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CLICK ME</button>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Button />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```